How Do I Continue Testing After a Failure Using Extent Reports
While using Extent Reports in Katalon, I noticed that I cannot continue a test after a failure. As in, after defining that something is a failure with test.fail, it will not continue to the rest of the tests in my code. I currently have 6 tests set up per test case.
Here's the relevant code (the ellipses are file paths and unrelated info):
switch (query) {
    Case 'Y':
        def ret2 = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('...'), '...')
        def som = ret2.contains('...')
        println som

        if (som == true) {
            test.pass('...')} 
                else {
            String base64Code = CustomKeywords.'(...).screenshot.takeScreenshotBase64'()    
    test.fail(MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64Code).build())
.info('...')}

break
    Case 'N':
        def ret3 = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('...']), 'class')
        def som3 = ret3.contains('column-checkbox-disabled')
        print som3

        if (som3 == true) {
            test.pass('...')} 
                else {
                String base64Code = CustomKeywords.'(...).screenshot.takeScreenshotBase64'()        
    test.fail(MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64Code).build()) .info('...')}

break

}

This is then repeated 5 more times for each permission I want to test. This is all wrapped in a try block, wrapped in a for loop. The extent.flush is the last line of code (outside of both).

You can try wrapping each test step or set of related steps in a try-catch block. This ensures that even if a step fails and a failure is logged, the rest of the test continues.
try {
    def ret2 = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('...'), '...')
    def som = ret2.contains('...')
    println som

    if (som == true) {
        test.pass('...')
    } else {
        String base64Code = CustomKeywords.'(...).screenshot.takeScreenshotBase64'()    
        test.fail(MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64Code).build())
        test.info('...')
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    test.fail("An error occurred: " + e.message)
}

